# jquery - match data from two arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, random

ive got following code:

```
var ColorsTable = ['#ff0000', '#34d104', '#18a0f4', '#ffffff', '#000000'];
var ColorsTableDescription = ['red-description', '#34d104-description', '#18a0f4-description', 'white-description', 'black-description'];

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('#random-it').click(function () {
    var Rand1 = ColorsTable[Math.floor(Math.random() * ColorsTable.length)];

$("#rama path").css("fill", Rand1);
var input = $('#kolor_ramy');
                input.val('');
                input.val(input.val() + Rand1);
                return false;
  });

});
```

How to achieve such solution, that after randomizing color from ColorsTable, it will display its name in input verbally (so taken from second array)? I should use IF's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I guessed your requirements right, you need something like this,

```
var ColorsTable = ['#ff0000', '#34d104', '#18a0f4', '#ffffff', '#000000'];
var ColorsTableDescription = ['red-description', '#34d104-description', '#18a0f4-description', 'white-description', 'black-description'];

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#random-it').click(function () {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ColorsTable.length);
        var color = ColorsTable[rand];

        $("#rama path").css("fill", color);
        $('#kolor_ramy').val(ColorsTableDescription[rand]);
        return false;
    });

});
```

i.e. same the random no in a variable. And use that same no to grab the color and color description.

Answer (score 1):

why not save the random index and take the color, color name from both arrays.

Comment: because he did not know about that, try enriching your answer, it's the right direction.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? I am using two array's because I need to have color name as a word (and the following code change a part of some elements through css and hex color)

Comment: @PawełSkaba he meant you should save this `Math.floor(Math.random() * ColorsTable.length)` into some variable such as called `index`, then you can access the color string via `ColorsTable[index]` and the color description via `ColorsTableDescription[index]`

Answer (score 0):

Since both array have the same length and each Color has a respective name, you have just to save the index you are randomizing and use to both get the color code and its description from second array:

```
var ColorsTable = ['#ff0000', '#34d104', '#18a0f4', '#ffffff', '#000000'];
var ColorsTableDescription = ['red-description', '#34d104-description', '#18a0f4-description', 'white-description', 'black-description'];

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

  $('#random-it').click(function () {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * ColorsTable.length);
  var Rand1 = ColorsTable[randomIndex];

  $("#rama path").css("fill", Rand1);
  var input = $('#kolor_ramy');
            input.val('');
            input.val(input.val() + ColorsTableDescription[randomIndex]); //Not quite sure if you intend to use it here but that is how you can get the respective description.
            return false;
  });

});
```